# App crashing when an image is selected

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to get an image using an intent but when I select the image, my application closes immediately.
This is my actual code:

```
private void capturarFoto() {

    String nameFoto = DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hhmmss", new Date()).toString();

    caminhoFoto = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),nameFoto);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(caminhoFoto));
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

It should call `onActivityResult` method after image selection, but unfortunately closes without any error in Logcat.

Is there something wrong?

**LOGCAT**
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the log? There is usually an exception with a stack trace

Comment: Have you implemented "onActivityResult"? did you set android.permission.CAMERA permission and the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission? Perhaps the file location is not accessible by the camera activity cause of permissions?

Comment: that logcat is not useful. please, add a break point at `getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1);`, clear the logcat, then run the app again, and a error should appear in the logcat. also, you can better copy/paste the messages instead of the screenshot.

Comment: @Carlos Robles, I did it, nevertheless doesn't works. Logcat is still empty when image is selected.

Comment: @Sdra Yes, "onActivityResult" is implemented, and permission is already on AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: do you know if the execution gets into the onActivityResult? can you also put a break point in the first line and see if it gets there? also, are you implementing that function in the fragment, or in the asociated activity?

Comment: @CarlosRobles, No, the execution doesn't gets into onActivityResult method, I'm implementing in the fragment.

Comment: try calling  `startActivityForResult(intent, 1);` instead of  `getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1);`

Comment: and if doesnt work, implement onActivityResult in the activity

Comment: any news? could you try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please replace `getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, 1);` with

```
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Then overwrite  `onActivityResult()` in your fragment, and in your activity like this

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

and check with a breakpoint if the execution gets in any of them.

Comment: great! im glad you fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

First of all make sure that your directory is created......

```
 final String dir =  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+ "/Folder/";
 File newdir = new File(dir); 
 newdir.mkdirs();
```

than ur function

```
private void capturarFoto() {
 String file = dir+DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hhmmss", new Date()).toString()+".jpg";


File newfile = new File(file);
            try {
                newfile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {}       

            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Log.d("Demo Pic", "Picture is saved");


    }
}
```

}

Make sure You add permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Best of luck :

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
String nameFoto = DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hhmmss", new Date()).toString();
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

To:

```
String nameFoto = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_hhmmss").format(new Date());
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

And make sure to add these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```